# Emacs+python C-c C-c not working

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, emacs

I am new to using emacs as python ide. 
I am using Emacs 24.5.1 with its default python mode.
I am writing a game with `pygame` and `pyganim` modules, but i am not able to run the code and test it because sometimes when i hit `C-c C-c` for `eval buffer` at the down window (i think it calls mini buffer?) i see only **Sent: import pygame...** (if i have imported pygame for example) and nothing more happens. How can i evaluate the whole code and why is this happening?

Comment: In principle another buffer should open with the python interpreter. try `C-x C-b` and check if you see a python buffer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start the interpreter first with `C-c C-p (run-python)`. Then you can `C-c C-c (python-shell-send-buffer)` to send the entire buffer to the python process or even `C-c C-r (python-sheel-send-region)` to only send the selected region to the python process. See more keybindings for your current buffer with `C-h m (describe-mode)`.